# Installing Ossec on an existing centos 6.4 machine

Tags: centos, security

I have an existing machine running centos 6.4. Is it ok to install now the [Ossec](http://www.ossec.net/) or it's not worth any more as the machine is already running for few months.

Which is the best mechanism to install because I saw one is from the source and some recommend atomicorp repo? Any recommendation please?

Comment: Can you throw in a link to what ossec is for others that may come across this question and don't know what it is?

Comment: @slm here is the link http://www.ossec.net/